# Python regex replace some digits in the middle with asterisk

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to replace some part of a 10 to 14 long digit with asterisk (*).

Actually it is two things I want to do:

1: Eliminate the country code if exist

2: Replace the middle 4 digits with asterisk

If I have: 9151234567 I want this: 0915****576

If I have: 09361234321 I want this: 0936****321

If I have +989201234841 I want this: 0920****841

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: A hint: match 4 digits at the start, match 3 digits at the end, replace the rest. But I'd rather not do these 4 disparate tasks using a (single) regexp. Write the trivial code that takes the country code and the `+` first.

Comment: @9000 Is it really trivial to remove the country code? [How many digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes) are in it?

Comment: For +1809xxxxxxxx is the country code +1809 or +1?

Comment: @MichaelGeary: if not exactly trivial, it's way simpler to do in a clean separate step, using a lookup table if needed, that to wrap it up into a regex, let alone a regex that does something else, too.

Comment: @ MichaelGeary and @9000 Give me your solution if the removal of country code is not trivial.

Comment: @9000: I agree completely. Much better to do this step first by itself. I was only questioning calling it "trivial", since it is actually a fairly interesting programming question on its own. Maybe even a good interview question: "Given a phone number in +nnnnnn... format, how would you identify and extract the country code? Feel free to use any resources at your disposal."

Comment: @SMahdiS: I don't have a solution. I've never coded this. But I believe the Wikipedia page I linked may have the information needed to develop a data structure and algorithm to do it. Why don't you take a look at the number patterns there and see what you can come up with, and then I'm sure a bunch of us could provide some helpful feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## With string slicing

```
nos =["9151234567", "09361234321", "+989201234841"]
print ['0'+a[-10:][:3]+'****'+a[-10:][-3:] for a in nos]
```

Output:

```
['0915****567', '0936****321', '0920****841']
```

`a[-10:]` will slice the last 10 digits.

---

## With regex:

```
import re

nos =["9151234567", "09361234321", "+989201234841"]
print [re.sub(r".*?(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d{3})$", r'0\1****\3', a) for a in nos]
```

Output:

```
['0915****567', '0936****321', '0920****841']
```

Comment: Is this possible using re.sub?

Comment: @SMahdiS Sure. Updated.

Comment: Try this: "+9609001234567". Our friends in [the Maldives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_the_Maldives) will be interested.

Comment: @MichaelGeary Output for `"+9609201234841"` -->  `'0920****841'`

Comment: @MYGz: I changed the example slightly and added a link to the relevant Wikipedia page to help clarify that this approach is wrong. The country code for the Maldives is "960", not "96". You should really go to the "how many digits" link I posted in a comment to the question and study it carefully.

Comment: @MichaelGeary Does it matter? I'm prepending an additional 0 after removing the country code. That `0` doesn't belongs to `960`

Comment: Let's try it for our friends at Cathay Pacific in Lebanon: "+9611510656". I don't mean to be rude, but this is not as simple as you may think.

Comment: @MichaelGeary Got you. I like that tone. I considered that all countries use 10 digits phone number. Maybe I'll check the wiki link that you gave later.

Comment: @MYGz: Thanks for not taking offense at my comments! This must be one of these things like dates and names that are so easy to get wrong. (Been there, done that!) If I weren't an old phone phreak from the '70s I might have not noticed the problems myself. ;-)

Comment: @MichaelGeary Thanks for pointing out though. I regret that I was so inconsiderate to some of our overseas friends :).

Comment: @MYGz: Oh no, you weren't inconsiderate at all! Putting out a possible solution, even if it isn't exactly the right one, is an important step on the way to finding the full answer. And if the code isn't quite right here, it may turn out to be a good example for other situations. I heard a story a few years ago that when the first Apollo astronauts went to the Moon, their spacecraft was never actually "on course". They were _always_ off course, but kept correcting back toward the right course. And that's how they got to the Moon. Glad to be your collaborator. :-)

Comment: @MichaelGeary Thank you for bringing us out of ignorance :). Nice to talk to you :)